# What does `|` mean in a goal-type in Agda?

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I'm reading the [Brutal Meta-introduction to Agda](http://oxij.org/note/BrutalDepTypes/).

In the section on "Rewriting with `with` and Unification" they mention a a case where a type of a goal goes from:

```agda
(filter p (a ∷ as) | p a) ≡ (filterN p (a ∷ as) | p a)
```

to

```agda
(filter p (a ∷ rs) | r) ≡ (filterN p (a ∷ rs) | r)
```

after adding a `with` clause.

I've seen similar notation show up in goals and error messages when writing Agda code.

I'm wondering, does it mean to have a variable to the right of `|`, in this notation? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: As far as I know, it means that Agda cannot fully calculate the goal as it depends on the part after the vertical bar `|` See this link for more explanation: https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2010/002257.html

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the definition for filter you see clauses like

```
... | true  = a ∷ (filter p as)
```

which are a shorthand for

```
filter p (a ∷ as) | true = a ∷ (filter p as)
```

The | notation in goals refer to these clauses, this means that e.g.

```
filter p (a ∷ as) | e
```

is equal to "a ∷ (filter p as)" when "e" is equal to "true".

In your case you have a variable 'r', so if you pattern match on it things will compute more.

Comment: This explains what the `|` means in a function definition (using `with`, but not what it means when present inside of a goal.

Comment: I was trying to say that inside a goal it means the same: it's notation for an expression whose value is defined by the clauses in the function definition. If there's no clause applicable then it does not compute further.